React Table filter by Column
I have this code that is a component for a table in react vite with tsx, right now I'm trying to apply some input filter in each column. I alredy have the filter logical, but the table is rendered base in the camp "camp", and because of this it only effectively filters the input of the column camp. How can I ajust the code to filter all the columns ?
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import "./TableFieldLayout.css";
import _ from "lodash";

interface TableFieldLayoutProps {
  sapPage: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  editableComponentId?: string;
}

interface DataItem {
  camp: string[];
  integrationStructureValues: string[];
  integrationCampValues: string[];
  ENDescriptionValues: string[];
  ESDescriptionValues: string[];
  PTDescriptionValues: string[];
  inputTypeValues: number[];
  [key: string]: any; // This allows for dynamic keys like `radio_${dataIndex}_${index}`
}

const TableFieldLayout: React.FC<TableFieldLayoutProps> = ({
  sapPage,
  children,
  editableComponentId,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [originalData, setOriginalData] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [companyCode, setCompanyCode] = useState<string>("");
  const [internalIdScreenLayout, setInternalIdScreenLayout] =
    useState<number>(0);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [update, setUpdate] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [dataChanged, setDataChanged] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [campsArray, setCampsArray] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [inputValuesArray, setInputValuesArray] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [integrationStructureArray, setIntegrationStructureArray] = useState<
    DataItem[]
  >([]);
  const [integrationCampArray, setIntegrationCampArray] = useState<DataItem[]>(
    []
  );
  const [enDescriptionArray, setEnDescriptionArray] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [esDescriptionArray, setEsDescriptionArray] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [ptDescriptionArray, setPtDescriptionArray] = useState<DataItem[]>([]);
  const [searchCamps, setSearchCamps] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchInputValues, setSearchInputValues] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchIntegrationStructure, setSearchIntegrationStructure] =
    useState<string>("");
  const [searchIntegrationCamp, setSearchIntegrationCamp] =
    useState<string>("");
  const [searchEnDescription, setSearchEnDescription] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchEsDescription, setSearchEsDescription] = useState<string>("");
  const [searchPtDescription, setSearchPtDescription] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
    const url = new URL(currentUrl);
    if (
      url.searchParams.get("companyCode") !== null &&
      url.searchParams.get("internalIdScreenLayout") !== null
    ) {
      const code = url.searchParams.get("companyCode") || "";
      const id = Number(url.searchParams.get("internalIdScreenLayout")) || 0;
      setCompanyCode(code);
      setInternalIdScreenLayout(id);
    }
  }, []);

  const initializeDefaultData = () => {
    setAllData((prevData) => {
      const newData = prevData.map((dataItem) => ({
        ...dataItem,
        inputTypeValues: Array(dataItem.camp.length).fill(0),
      }));
      return newData;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(allData);
  }, [allData]);

  const addData = (newData: DataItem) => {
    setAllData((prevData) => {
      const dataExists = prevData.some((data) => _.isEqual(data, newData));
      if (!dataExists) {
        return [...prevData, newData];
      }
      return prevData;
    });
    setOriginalData((prevData) => {
      let exists = prevData.some((data) => _.isEqual(data, newData));
      if (!exists) {
        let newDataClone = _.cloneDeep(newData);
        return [...prevData, newDataClone];
      }
      return prevData;
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3000/sap-page/${companyCode}/${internalIdScreenLayout}/${sapPage}`
        );
        const responseData = response.data;

        if (Array.isArray(responseData)) {
          const data = responseData.map((entry: any) => {
            const dynamicData: any = {};

            originalData.forEach((data, dataIndex) => {
              data.camp.forEach((suffix, index) => {
                const keyEN = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionEN`;
                const keyES = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionES`;
                const keyPT = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionPT`;
                const keyCamps = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-camps`;
                const keyIntegrationCamp = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationCamp`;
                const keyIntegrationStructure = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationStructure`;
                const keyInputType = `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-inputType`;

                dynamicData.ENDescriptionValues =
                  dynamicData.ENDescriptionValues || [];
                dynamicData.ENDescriptionValues.push(entry[keyEN] || "");

                dynamicData.ESDescriptionValues =
                  dynamicData.ESDescriptionValues || [];
                dynamicData.ESDescriptionValues.push(entry[keyES] || "");

                dynamicData.PTDescriptionValues =
                  dynamicData.PTDescriptionValues || [];
                dynamicData.PTDescriptionValues.push(entry[keyPT] || "");

                dynamicData.camp = dynamicData.camp || [];
                dynamicData.camp.push(entry[keyCamps] || "");

                dynamicData.integrationCampValues =
                  dynamicData.integrationCampValues || [];
                dynamicData.integrationCampValues.push(
                  entry[keyIntegrationCamp] || ""
                );

                dynamicData.integrationStructureValues =
                  dynamicData.integrationStructureValues || [];
                dynamicData.integrationStructureValues.push(
                  entry[keyIntegrationStructure] || ""
                );

                dynamicData.inputTypeValues = dynamicData.inputTypeValues || [];
                dynamicData.inputTypeValues.push(entry[keyInputType] || 0);
              });
            });

            return dynamicData;
          });

          setAllData(data);
          setUpdate(true);
          console.log("Número de entries:", data.length);
        } else {
          console.error("API retornou dados inválidos:", responseData);
          initializeDefaultData();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data from API:", error);
        initializeDefaultData();
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (companyCode && internalIdScreenLayout && sapPage) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [companyCode, internalIdScreenLayout, sapPage]);

  const handleUpdate = async () => {
    if (allData.length === 0 || allData.length !== originalData.length) {
      console.error(
        "allData não está corretamente populado. Verifique addData e outras funções de manipulação de dados."
      );
      return;
    }

    let isValid = true;

    const dataToSend: any = {};
    originalData.forEach((data, dataIndex) => {
      data.camp.forEach((suffix, index) => {
        if (allData[dataIndex]) {
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-camps`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].camp[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationStructure`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].integrationStructureValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationCamp`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].integrationCampValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionEN`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].ENDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionES`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].ESDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionPT`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].PTDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-inputType`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].inputTypeValues[index];

          if (
            allData[dataIndex].inputTypeValues[index] > 0 &&
            (allData[dataIndex].ENDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "" ||
              allData[dataIndex].ESDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "" ||
              allData[dataIndex].PTDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "")
          ) {
            isValid = false;
          }
        } else {
          console.error(
            `Índice ${dataIndex} está fora do intervalo de allData.`
          );
        }
      });
    });

    if (!isValid) {
      alert(
        "Por favor, preencha todos os campos nas linhas que não estão ocultas."
      );
      return;
    }

    dataToSend["sapPage"] = sapPage;
    dataToSend["companyCode"] = companyCode;
    dataToSend["internalIdScreenLayout"] = internalIdScreenLayout;

    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        `http://localhost:3000/sap-page/${companyCode}/${internalIdScreenLayout}/${sapPage}`,
        dataToSend
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      alert("Dados atualizados com sucesso!");
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending data to the API:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (allData.length === 0 || allData.length !== originalData.length) {
      console.error(
        "allData não está corretamente populado. Verifique addData e outras funções de manipulação de dados."
      );
      return;
    }

    let isValid = true;

    const dataToSend: any = {};
    originalData.forEach((data, dataIndex) => {
      data.camp.forEach((suffix, index) => {
        if (allData[dataIndex]) {
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-camps`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].camp[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationStructure`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].integrationStructureValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-integrationCamp`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].integrationCampValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionEN`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].ENDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionES`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].ESDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-descriptionPT`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].PTDescriptionValues[index];
          dataToSend[
            `${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-inputType`
          ] = allData[dataIndex].inputTypeValues[index];

          if (
            allData[dataIndex].inputTypeValues[index] > 0 &&
            (allData[dataIndex].ENDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "" ||
              allData[dataIndex].ESDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "" ||
              allData[dataIndex].PTDescriptionValues[index].trim() === "")
          ) {
            isValid = false;
          }
        } else {
          console.error(
            `Índice ${dataIndex} está fora do intervalo de allData.`
          );
        }
      });
    });

    if (!isValid) {
      alert(
        "Por favor, preencha todos os campos nas linhas que não estão ocultas."
      );
      return;
    }

    dataToSend["sapPage"] = sapPage;
    dataToSend["companyCode"] = companyCode;
    dataToSend["internalIdScreenLayout"] = internalIdScreenLayout;

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3000/sap-page",
        dataToSend
      );
      console.log(response.data);
      alert("Dados salvos com sucesso!");
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending data to the API:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleRadioChangeLocal = (
    dataIndex: number,
    index: number,
    value: any,
    integrationStructureValue: string,
    integrationCampValue: string
  ) => {
    setAllData((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const currentData = newState[dataIndex];

      if (currentData && currentData.inputTypeValues) {
        newState[dataIndex] = {
          ...currentData,
          inputTypeValues: [
            ...currentData.inputTypeValues.slice(0, index),
            value === null ? "" : value,
            ...currentData.inputTypeValues.slice(index + 1),
          ],
        };
      }

      return newState;
    });

    setDataChanged(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (
    newValue: string,
    dataIndex: number,
    index: number,
    field: string
  ) => {
    setAllData((prevData) => {
      const newData = [...prevData];
      newData[dataIndex][field][index] = newValue;
      return newData;
    });
    setDataChanged(true);
  };

  const confirmAndHandleUpdate = () => {
    if (dataChanged) {
      if (
        window.confirm(
          "Há alterações não salvas. Deseja salvar antes de continuar?"
        )
      ) {
        handleUpdate();
      }
    } else {
      handleUpdate();
    }
  };

  const confirmAndHandleSubmit = () => {
    if (dataChanged) {
      if (
        window.confirm(
          "Há alterações não salvas. Deseja salvar antes de continuar?"
        )
      ) {
        handleSubmit();
      }
    } else {
      handleSubmit();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    originalData.forEach((data) => {
      setCampsArray(data.camp);
      setInputValuesArray(data.inputTypeValues);
      setIntegrationStructureArray(data.integrationStructureArray);
      setIntegrationStructureArray(data.integrationStructureValues);
      setIntegrationCampArray(data.integrationCampValues);
      setEnDescriptionArray(data.ENDescriptionValues);
      setEsDescriptionArray(data.ESDescriptionValues);
      setPtDescriptionArray(data.PTDescriptionValues);
    });
  }, [originalData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = originalData.map((dataItem) => ({
      camp: dataItem.camp.filter((camp) =>
        camp.toLowerCase().includes(searchCamps.toLowerCase())
      ),
      integrationStructureValues: dataItem.integrationStructureValues.filter((item) =>
        item.toLowerCase().includes(searchIntegrationStructure.toLowerCase())
      ),
      integrationCampValues: dataItem.integrationCampValues.filter((value) =>
        value.toLowerCase().includes(searchIntegrationCamp.toLowerCase())
      ),
      ENDescriptionValues: dataItem.ENDescriptionValues.filter((value) =>
        value.toLowerCase().includes(searchEnDescription.toLowerCase())
      ),
      ESDescriptionValues: dataItem.ESDescriptionValues.filter((value) =>
        value.toLowerCase().includes(searchEsDescription.toLowerCase())
      ),
      PTDescriptionValues: dataItem.PTDescriptionValues.filter((value) =>
        value.toLowerCase().includes(searchPtDescription.toLowerCase())
      ),
    })).filter((dataItem) =>
      dataItem.camp.length > 0 &&
      dataItem.integrationStructureValues.length > 0 &&
      dataItem.integrationCampValues.length > 0 &&
      dataItem.ENDescriptionValues.length > 0 &&
      dataItem.ESDescriptionValues.length > 0 &&
      dataItem.PTDescriptionValues.length > 0
    );
  
    setFilteredData(filtered);
  }, [
    originalData,
    searchCamps,
    searchIntegrationStructure,
    searchIntegrationCamp,
    searchEnDescription,
    searchEsDescription,
    searchPtDescription,
  ]);
  
  const fields = [
  { key: 'camp', label: 'Camp' },
  { key: 'integrationStructureValues', label: 'Integration Structure' },
  { key: 'integrationCampValues', label: 'Integration Camp' },
  { key: 'ENDescriptionValues', label: 'EN Description' },
  { key: 'ESDescriptionValues', label: 'ES Description' },
  { key: 'PTDescriptionValues', label: 'PT Description' },
];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("filtered data", filteredData);
  }, [filteredData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table-field-layout">
        {React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
          React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>, { addData })
        )}
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr className="table-field-layout-tittles">
              <th className="camps-name-th">{t("camp")}</th>
              <th>{t("hide")}</th>
              <th>{t("display")}</th>
              <th>{t("optional")}</th>
              <th>{t("mandatory")}</th>
              <th>{t("integrationStructure")}</th>
              <th>{t("integrationCamp")}</th>
              <th>{t("ENDescription")}</th>
              <th>{t("ESDescription")}</th>
              <th>{t("PTDescription")}</th>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchCamps}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchCamps(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchInputValues}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchInputValues(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchIntegrationStructure}
                onChange={(ev) =>
                  setSearchIntegrationStructure(ev.target.value)
                }
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchIntegrationCamp}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchIntegrationCamp(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchEnDescription}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchEnDescription(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchEsDescription}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchEsDescription(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={searchPtDescription}
                onChange={(ev) => setSearchPtDescription(ev.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {filteredData.length > 0 &&
              filteredData.map(
                (data, dataIndex) =>
                  data.camp.length > 0 &&
                  data.camp.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={`${dataIndex}-${index}`}>
                      {dataIndex === parseInt(editableComponentId) ? (
                        <td>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            value={item}
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              handleInputChange(
                                e.target.value,
                                dataIndex,
                                index,
                                "camp"
                              )
                            }
                          />
                        </td>
                      ) : (
                        <td
                          className={`camps-name-td ${
                            index % 2 === 0 ? "zebra-white" : "zebra-dark"
                          }`}
                        >
                          {t(item)}
                        </td>
                      )}
                      {[0, 1, 2, 3].map((radioValue) => (
                        <td key={`radio-${dataIndex}-${index}-${radioValue}`}>
                          <input
                            type="radio"
                            name={`${data.integrationStructureValues[index]}-${data.integrationCampValues[index]}-inputType`}
                            value={radioValue.toString()}
                            checked={
                              data.inputTypeValues &&
                              data.inputTypeValues[index] === radioValue
                            }
                            onChange={() =>
                              handleRadioChangeLocal(
                                dataIndex,
                                index,
                                radioValue,
                                data.integrationStructureValues[index],
                                data.integrationCampValues[index]
                              )
                            }
                          />
                        </td>
                      ))}
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={data.integrationStructureValues[index]}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleInputChange(
                              e.target.value,
                              dataIndex,
                              index,
                              "integrationStructureValues"
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={data.integrationCampValues[index]}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleInputChange(
                              e.target.value,
                              dataIndex,
                              index,
                              "integrationCampValues"
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={data.ENDescriptionValues[index]}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleInputChange(
                              e.target.value,
                              dataIndex,
                              index,
                              "ENDescriptionValues"
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={data.ESDescriptionValues[index]}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleInputChange(
                              e.target.value,
                              dataIndex,
                              index,
                              "ESDescriptionValues"
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          value={data.PTDescriptionValues[index]}
                          onChange={(e) =>
                            handleInputChange(
                              e.target.value,
                              dataIndex,
                              index,
                              "PTDescriptionValues"
                            )
                          }
                        />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))
              )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div className="table-field-layout-button-container">
        {update ? (
          <button
            onClick={confirmAndHandleUpdate}
            className="table-field-layout-button"
          >
            {t("update")}
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            onClick={confirmAndHandleSubmit}
            className="table-field-layout-button"
          >
            {t("submit")}
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableFieldLayout;


